# Unable to run client endpoint code for websocket implementation in Java (Class file not found error)

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, tyrus

I am trying to create a client socket for a web sockets implementation.

I am using the code from:

https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client

The code is importing some `javax.websocket.*` class files.

I have downloaded the jar files from the following link:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar

I set the classpath to the path of the class files during compilation.

The code is compiled, but when I am trying to run the code, it gives an error that the class file is not found.

The link above told that it used tyrus as the websocket API, but as I have glassfish installed in my Ubuntu system, it already contains all the jars for the tyrus.

How can I run the code and fix the dependencies?
[snapshot of client code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2dpW.png)

Comment: Please insert full stacktrace so we can help you better. :)

Comment: meenakshi@hp-PC:~/Downloads/javaee-api-7.0$ javac -cp ':.javax.websocket' WSClient.java
meenakshi@hp-PC:~/Downloads/javaee-api-7.0$ java -cp ':.javax.websocket' WSClient
Error: Could not find or load main class WSClient

Comment: This is the error i am getting. And as i told this code requires import of javax.websocket.* classes ,but i have mentioned the class path during compilation.